# Increase error font size in XCode

Tags: xcode, editor

Is it possible to make these tiny messages larger? I didn't find it preferences.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed: head over to **Xcode - Preferences** and find the **Fonts and Colors** section. Switch to the **Console Tab** and select an option you want to change (typically Executable Console Output and Debugger Console Output appear in the debugger).

Now click the tiny little T icon at the bottom and change the font to something more palatable. The default font is Menlo 11.

Alternatively you can switch to either of the Presentation presets, which will increase the font size for the debugger and your code font (good for screencasts).

[image]

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the font size of the tiny red error messages is governed by the space available: if you make the default font size larger (or the size of any of the elements on that line), the error message will expand to fit.

An alternative is to show the issue navigator on the left, which has larger type, especially if you fiddle around in the preferences and allow more than 3 lines per entry, or whatever the default setting is.